# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'is_visible_on_front' in where clause is ambiguous after data import in magento

Tags: magento

Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'is_visible_on_front' in where clause is ambiguous after data import in magento

Comment: Explain what you have done, at where you get this error and put that code. Then only we can able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You must specifiy the table name for the column `is_visible_on_front`. For example: `tableName.is_visible_on_front`